# How to get the value from N dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with an options, this options have the number of inputs that user want to draw, after that user can type information in that inputs and finally they have to click a button to display that values, right now I'm doing this like this:

```
var value1 = $('#Input1').val();
```

The problem here is that the user can create a maximum of 200 inputs, so if I keep doing this in the above way I'll need to do that with the 200 inputs and it's a lot of code lines, my question is if exits a way to get the value of N inputs, I draw the inputs dynamically with a for loop, so all the input ID is something like `Input(MyForVariable), Input1, Input2... etc`, so maybe I'm thinking in create another loop to get the value of that inputs, here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sel').change(function () {
    draw();
  });
  
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    show();
  });
});

function draw() {
  var selected = $('#sel').val();
  var html = "";
  
  for (i = 1; i <= selected; i++) {
    html += '<input type="text" id="Imput' + i + '" />';
  }
  $('#forms').html(html);
}

function show() {
  var total = $('#sel').val();
  
  if (total == 2) {
    var val1 = $('#Imput1').val();
    var val2 = $('#Imput2').val();
    
    alert(val1 + val2);
  }
  
   if (total == 3) {
    var val1 = $('#Imput1').val();
    var val2 = $('#Imput2').val();
     var val3 = $('#Imput3').val();
    
    alert(val1 + val2 + val3);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id="sel">
  <option value="2">A</option>
  <option value="3">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
  <option value="5">D</option>
</select>

<div id="forms">
</div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Simply add class to each input then loop the inputs with respect to class and get back it values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your `input`s inside a container, and loop through them:

```js
$('#add').on('click', function () {
  $('<input />').appendTo('#myinputs');
});


$('#get').on('click', function () {
  var values = [];
  
  $('#myinputs input').each(function () {
    values.push(this.value);
  });
  
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myinputs">
  <input />
</div>

<button id="add">Add another input</button>

<hr />

<button id="get">Get values</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set some attribute and get all elements that has it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sel').change(function () {
    draw();
  });
  
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    show();
  });
});

function draw() {
  var selected = $('#sel').val();
  var html = "";
  
  for (i = 1; i <= selected; i++) {
    html += '<input type="text" id="Imput' + i + '" to-count />';
  }
  $('#forms').html(html);
}

function show() {
  var total = $('#sel').val();
  var sum = "";
  var inputs = $('[to-count]');
  
  console.log(inputs.length);
  for (let i=0; i < inputs.length ; i++){
    sum += inputs[i].value;      
  }

  alert(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id="sel">
  <option value="2">A</option>
  <option value="3">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
  <option value="5">D</option>
</select>

<div id="forms">
</div>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always loop throw your inputs like this:

```
var myInputArray = [];

$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
   myInputArray.push($(this).val());
}
```

Then you can get your values by locking in the array:

```
alert(myInputArray[0]) //The first value of the array => first input
```

Comment: Your selector isn't selecting what you think it should be selecting (you need to remove the space).

Comment: Thanks, I was in a bit of hurry when I wrote it

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values for each of the Select options by using the following code:

```
$("#sel option").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: When to use code snippet, the code need to works. In this case, maybe can be better only code format for the asnwer.

Comment: @LucasCosta - Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, so better :)